# splitting binary string such that it is a power of 5

Tags: java, string

I am trying to split a binary string such that it is a possible to cut string into smallest positive integer, each of them being the power of 5. If there is no such pieces return -1 instead.

```
public class Power {
    public int numsOfWays(String s) {
        long[] f = new long[s.length() + 1];
        f[0] = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= s.length(); ++i) {
            f[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
                if (s.charAt(j - 1) == '0') {
                    continue;
                }
                int num = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(j - 1, i), 2);
                if (isPower(num)) {
                    f[i] = Math.min(f[i], f[j - 1] + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        return f[s.length()] == Integer.MAX_VALUE ? -1 : (int) f[s.length()];
    }

    private boolean isPower(long val) {
        if (val == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        int n = (int) (Math.log(val) / Math.log(5));
        return Math.pow(5, n) == val;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Power b = new Power();
        System.out.println(b.numsOfWays("111011100110101100101110111"));
    }
}
```

I am getting this error :-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11101110011010110010111011100000"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)
    at abc.Power.numsOfWays(Power.java:13)
    at abc.Power.main(Power.java:33)
```

Comment: Can you show sample input and your expected output?  That would make it easier to understand your question.

Comment: in the code you posted is no Integer,parseInt()

Comment: sample input:111011100110101100101110111 and its output must be:5

Comment: If I did not miscount the digits, the number 11101110011010110010111011100000 is too large to fit into an `int`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sample code:11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 answer: 50

Comment: @Henry i have replaced int by long but it's giving garbage value in the result.

Comment: Your `isPower` method may suffer from rounding errors, I did not understand the rest of your program (nor did I fully get the problem you are trying to solve)

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is in Line 13 of your code:
The line:

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(j - 1, i), 2);
```

has a problem because the value is too long for intto handle.

Change it to:

```
long num = Long.parseLong(s.substring(j - 1, i), 2);
```

and it should work.

**EDIT**: The Entire Code looks like this:

```
public class Power {
    public int numsOfWays(String s) {
        long[] f = new long[s.length() + 1];
        f[0] = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= s.length(); ++i) {
            f[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
                if (s.charAt(j - 1) == '0') {
                    continue;
                }
                long num = Long.parseLong(s.substring(j - 1, i), 2);
                if (isPower(num)) {
                    f[i] = Math.min(f[i], f[j - 1] + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        return f[s.length()] == Integer.MAX_VALUE ? -1 : (int) f[s.length()];
    }

    private boolean isPower(long val) {
        if (val == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        int n = (int) (Math.log(val) / Math.log(5));
        return Math.pow(5, n) == val;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Power b = new Power();
        System.out.println(b.numsOfWays("111011100110101100101110111")); // 5
        System.out.println(b.numsOfWays("11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111")); // 50
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
5
50
```

Comment: Which Language/compiler are you using? Works perfectly fine on Java 8, both online and on my local machine.. 
https://repl.it/G0CM/0